# SQL server query for selecting data with 5 seconds interval

Tags: sql-server

Can anyone tell me T-SQL script for selecting data with the interval of 5 seconds? I have a SCADA system which logs data for a parameter every second but i want to retrieve data with interval of 5 sec, also the start time will be decided by user.
Example if start = 10:00:01 and end is 11:00:00 I want to see data at 10:00:06, 10:00:11, 10:00:16... but not data at 10:00:02, 10:00:03 to 10:00:05, and between 10:00:07 and 10:00:10

Comment: what do you want to do with the data in each interval ? aggregate them? (ie. sum or average)

Comment: no,i want to see that data that is logged in table with interval of 5 seconds.

Comment: i have a SCADA system which logs data for a parameter every second but i want to retrieve data with interval of 5 sec, also the start time will be decided by user.

Comment: if start = 10:00:00 and end is 11:00:00 you want to see data at 10:00:00, 10:00:05, 10:00:10... but not data at 10:00:01, 10:00:02 to 10:00:04, and between 10:00:06 and 10:00:09 ?

Comment: yes!! exactly julien...

Comment: it would help if you rephrase you question and add more info

Comment: ok i will rephrase my question..

Comment: Can you make it work with the answer below ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I first create dummy data every second from 10:00 to 10:16

```
declare @data table(creation datetime2);
declare @start datetime = '20150930 10:00:00';
declare @end datetime;

-- create dummy data from 10:00:00 to 10:16:40
with ids(n) as (
    Select ROW_NUMBER() over(Order by n) From (
        Select 1 From (values(1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)) as x1(n)
        Cross Join (values(1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)) as x2(n)
        Cross Join (values(1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1)) as x3(n)
    ) as x(n)
)
Insert Into @data(creation)
Select DATEADD(second, n, @start) From ids
```

I then calculate the difference in second between Start date and creation date and use modulo 5 (%5) in order to find date every 5s:

```
set @start = '20150930 10:01:03'
set @end = '20150930 10:05:00';

Select *
    , DATEDIFF(second, creation, @start)
    , DATEDIFF(second, creation, @start) % 5
From @data
Where (DATEDIFF(second, creation, @start) % 5) = 0
    and creation >= @start and creation <= @end
```

Output:

```
creation                    DATEDIFF  Modulo    (No column name)
2015-09-30 10:01:03.0000000 0         0
2015-09-30 10:01:08.0000000 -5        0
2015-09-30 10:01:13.0000000 -10       0
...                         ...       ...
```

You can see that DATEDIFF is always n*5 and there Modulo = 0

Comment: THANX A LOT JULIEN ..IT REALLY HELPED ME..TYVM

Answer (score -1):

You should use the while loop and store the data in a temp table then retrieve result fro the temp table

ref-
https://www.toadworld.com/platforms/sql-server/w/wiki/10221.while-loops